# Nav is all cramped up

Tags: css, nav

Just got help with a z-index issue - thanks guys!

I want this site too look like this: http://cl.ly/IWgu

And when you hover over the parent pages it reveals the submenu(s) of that page, etc.

Here is the site: http://tempsmz.hostzi.com/

Problem is, everythings all cramped up! I have 2 parent pages and 3 submenus for the first parent page, but it's all cramped.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code and/or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to look at?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tArmf/

Comment: The site certainly has everything, but it would also make it easier for others to help you if they didn't have to go through all your source code and styling. It's really just a matter of courtesy - others are willing to put in time to help you, so if you make it easier for them I'm sure it would be much appreciated. Thanks for the jsFiddle by the way.

Comment: Post an answer so I can mark it right. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, just did what they said over at the z-index thread. I just needed to add position:relative to the #siteHeader and #site divs then specify a background color via css. Thanks guys, this site rocks!

Comment: Good to see you got it working. I was just about to post that the cramped menu items was from `position: absolute` for the elements in `#nav`, but if it worked for you to change `siteHeader` and `#site` then that's fine as well. If this solved your problem, you should be able to mark your own answer as correct (after I two days I believe).